# ¿Como evitar que accedan a las rutas de mi proyecto web Spring sin antes haber logeado?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

tengo un proyecto web en Spring MVC y quisiera saber que método o controlador se puede implementar para que las demás rutas o vistas del sistema no sean accedidas por usuarios no logeados directamente por la url, y si se intenta ello que me redireccione a la vista login.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: échale un vistazo a Spring security, tiene todo lo que necesitas https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring